# Why doesn't Django's test command recognize some options?

Tags: django, django-testing, django-manage.py

I'm running a project on Django 1.8.12 and I'd like to preserve test database between runs as [described in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database). Even though the `test` command itself lists the `-k/--keepdb` option in help text, using it fails:

```
vagrant@vagrant /vagrant/project (master) $ python manage.py test -k myapp.tests.testcase
nosetests myapp.tests.testcase -k --verbosity=1
Usage: manage.py [options]

manage.py: error: no such option: -k

vagrant@vagrant /vagrant/project (master) $ python manage.py test --keepdb myapp.tests.testcase
nosetests myapp.tests.testcase --keepdb --verbosity=1
Usage: manage.py [options]

manage.py: error: no such option: --keepdb
```

Calling the same command with some other options, e.g. `-q` or `--failfast` works fine. On the other hand, some other listed options such as `--no-color` fail in a similar manner.

Am I missing something here? How can I pass these options to the command?

Comment: Are you using `django.test.TestCase` in the tests, or `unittest.TestCase`?

Comment: I'm using `django.test.TestCase`, but I don't think it matters much since they most likely never get called, the error terminates the execution before that. Switching to `unittest.TestCase` or defining `class TestCase(object): pass` causes the same error message when `-k` option is used.

Comment: Can you run tests in other apps, or do they fail too? The [Django 1.8 source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.12/django/test/runner.py#L55) does know it.

Comment: I do get the same error when trying to run tests in other apps within the same Django project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and issue was having the TEST_RUNNER set to `django_nose` in the project settings.  So in ../settings/local.py, commenting out or removing this:

`TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'`

allows the --keepdb switch to be used.

Comment: Indeed, --keepdb seems to be an option for Django's default testrunner. I however prefer to use NoseTests, so running the tests with `REUSE_DB=1 python manage.py test` does the trick for me.

Marking the answer as correct since it helped me to find a solution that was suitable for me.

Comment: More recent versions of `django_nose` pass through the `--keepdb` options, so another solution is to upgrade that Python package (e.g. for me, upgrading `django-nose` from 1.4.1 to 1.4.4 allowed `--keepdb` to work)